# R plotlly add_trace issue when x-axis values are POSIXct

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I wish it could be much easier for us to add reference lines in `plotly` like using `geom_vline` or `geom_hline` in `ggplot2` or even the `abline` in base R.

We can use `add_trace` function to mimic the `geom_hline` but this time it seems I am adding the wrong x values.

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

D = data.frame(
  y = round(rnorm(10),1),
  x = structure(c(1498640394, 1498641854, 1498642201, 1498642515, 1498642749, 
            1498643011, 1498643247, 1498643499, 1498643735, 1498643992), 
            tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
)

D$DATE_TIME = lubridate::ymd_hms(D$x)

MIN = min(D$x)

MAX = max(D$x)

H = 0

plot_ly(D, x = ~x, y = ~ y, type = "scatter", mode ="lines+markers") %>% 
  add_trace(x = c(MIN, MAX), y = c(H, H), name = "Reference", mode = "lines", line=list(color="red",dash="dash"))
```

I get 
[image]

The reference line goes way wrong. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this question:

```
MIN = min(D$x) - 28800

MAX = max(D$x) - 28800
```

Then the chart is correct for now.